# Align Div side by side is not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to show two div side by side.I have tried everything I found on the internet.But It's not working.One of the div is slightly below to the other div.
I have also tried Bootstrap.I am not expert in designing.So,help me out.
The div are oriented like this:

```
 Div-1
                                          Div-2
```

My code is here:

```
  <div style="display:inline-block;float:left"> 

           <ul  name="category" id="category" class="navigation" >

           <a class="main" >Brand</a> 

           @foreach ($brands as $brand)

                <li class='n1'><a href="{{$brand->id}}" class="selected" data-id="{{$brand->id}}">{{$brand->brand}}</a></li>
            @endforeach

        </ul>

  </div> 



<div style="display:inline-block;float:right">
   <ul class="navigation" name="model" id="model" >
          <a class="main" >Model</a>


           </ul>
</div>
```

And My CSS:

```
         .navigation {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 250px; 
  height: 40px; 

  background: #95C11F;
}

.navigation li { 
  width: 250px; 
  height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: What should happen when their total size gets wider than the browser window?

Comment: I think your code will not work for me.

Comment: If you don't know this,plaease don't comment.

Comment: To who do you write that??

Comment: To You.Don't Mind.

Comment: Appears to me it is you who don't know, since you can't make this work. Do you want my help or not?

Comment: then,help me.Let's see how much you know.

Comment: Let me know if my answer and offline help solved your question. If it did, please consider accept it, if not, let me know what's missing.

Comment: If you start accepting answers given on your questions, people here might put in more of their personal time answering more of them, also, future users benefit from knowing which answer best solved a certain question.

Comment: Sorry to say,but your answer did not work for me.I have found another way.

Answer (score 0):

something like [this](http://codepen.io/yurigor/pen/QKpmKX)?

```
<div class="brand">Brand</div>
<div class="model">Model</div>
```

-

```
.brand, .model {
  float:left;
  padding:5px;
  width: 250px; 
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
.brand {
  background: rgba(88,0,0,0.5);
}
.model {
  background: rgba(0,88,0,0.5);
}
```

Comment: No,Nothing Like This.

Comment: Explain more specific what do you need then.
May be draw some mock how it should look like.
You said you want two divs side by side - you got it, what's wrong?

Answer (score -1):

First of all you can't add `<a>` tag in `<ul>` and you don't need to add `display:inline-block;` if you are using `float` there. So, first resolve these things and check again. If still you are getting problem then please share a screenshot so I can understand what's exactly happening.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer, I recommend you either update it to be an answer, or delete it. Some might down vote posts like this

Comment: I can not place <a> outside of my <ul>.My design will be ruined.Even if i do so,it's not working.